# Installation of Windows Server 2012 R2 x64

Tags: windows, installation, windows-server-2008-r2, iso-image

I regularly swap OS during a development process. With "normal" OSs I can expect and install (.iso) to reach <=4GB, no problem, I usually use DVD. Now, I need to do some testing with Windows Server 2012 R2, this .iso is HUGE at 5.2GB!

The problem I have is that this will not fit on a single DVD, and it will not fit on a bootable USB stick due to file size limitations of FAT32.

I could split the file over separate DVDs, but I don't think this is possible from experience (am I wrong?).

My question is a simple one, how can I install Windows Server 2012 R2?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What about a Virtual Machine (VMWare Workstation or VM Virtual BOX)?

Answer (score 2):

NTFS-formatted USB stick.

Command prompt (run as administrator):

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk N (N = the disk you want to format)
clean
create partition primary
active
format fs=ntfs quick
assign
```

After you have done this, just copy all the files of WS2012R2 on the USB. it should work without additionally requiring bootsect command (bootsect.exe/nt60 N:). This command is needed only if the USB will not boot, but it should not happen on WS2012.

Comment: Thanks but I am getting "BOOTMGR is missing"

Comment: That should be format fs=ntfs quick... NOT format fs-ntfs quick (eq sign instead of dash)

Answer (score 1):

You have to burn the iso on a double-layer DVD, where you can store up to 8.5 GB.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVD%2BR_DL

You can also use an USB key in FAT32, as you have to copy installation files on it (not the .iso) which aren't bigger than the FAT32 limit (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn293258.aspx)

Comment: DL DVDs are a solution but can cause integrity errors for a lot of ODDs. And that will prevent the OS from installing.

Comment: @Overmind - Since when exactly?  I have been using double layered DVDs for a decade, the movie industry has been doing it for longer than that, I have never heard of a problem with double layered disks.

Comment: I'd vote this down in *this* particular instance as it's generalised advice, not tailored for this question.  The 2012 R2 disk contains some files which are > 4GB and won't copy to a FAT32 volume.